# Eclipselink - Lazy Load Behavor after Close EntityManager [Best Practice - Better way and how to live]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, lazy-loading

I would like to ask for help on eclipselink (lazy load).

As we all know **Eclipselink**, has a behavior somewhat different from **Hibernate**, *unfortunately* or *fortunately* it allows to perform the **lazy load after closing the EntityManager**

I've researched a lot on this subject and found nothing in it, is there any way to override this behavior?

Any native paramemter? I noticed that there is anti-pattern for this, but for all the content I read, this would not be the advised way of doing this.

I would very much like a way to bar this behavior.

I tried to use the parameter:

```
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.is-lazy" value="false" />
```

But without success.

I tried to find some property, but I was not successful either :
[List of Properties of Eclipselink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/toc.htm)

For more experienced developers, how can I improve this behavior within my system? Is there anything I can do about it?

I would like to go a bit more, what benefits we gained from this behavior and what would be a good practice on top of it

Comment: This article refers to Object DB but I guess it's the same behavior of Hibernate: http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/155

Comment: What value is there to your object model throwing an exception when accessing something that hasn't been fetched?  If you really need it, you can add the behavior to your accessors, or implement your own valueholder subclass that performs the check and throws the desired exception.  The how involves using customizers to change your lazy mappings to use your custom indirection class.  There aren't examples easily found but https://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_Mappings_(ELUG)#Indirection_.28Lazy_Loading.29 might help.

Comment: I have no exception, in fact I want to eliminate this behavior from being able to fetch the children of my entity at any time, I would like to be able to behave more closely with Hibernate